# Stackoverflow Careers Deconstructing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, user-interface

This is more just a raw idea than a question. I am interested browsing careers by various criteria in a relatively simple way. While I really like the StackOverflow Careers page, I would like to see it in a different way also. I perhaps would like to add some interesting visualizations (using d3.js maybe) of the careers site by various dimensions and be able to drill through to jobs based on these dimensions.

I have put together a quick I idea based upon the atom feed :

http://anexiledderryman.com/stackoverflow

I would be interested in taking this concept to the next level with d3.js perhaps and creating some deeper linking to the actual jobs.

Any comments thoughts feedback welcome!

Cheers
Shay

Comment: Works a little slowly - I thought the page was completely broken when I first opened it, as it was blank. Took a little while for anything to appear.

Comment: yeah, its using YQL to transform the feed, some patience is required, will add in a loading overlay, also the knockoutjs and underscore parsing of the feed are probably contributing to the length of time to run.

Comment: OK, so the latency is totally to do with the first call to YQL for the complete feed hence the lag. I have added in a loading view to provide immediate feedback to the user. Apologies for the blank white page when hitting this page for the first time.

Comment: I have added a little d3.js example here to show how the cities might look in a bubble chart : http://jsfiddle.net/shaydoc/2cfv2/6/show/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're actually working on something like this but localized to a specific city. For example you'll be able to go to the New York page and see a breakdown of the most popular programming languages. You may even be able to see them now. We're running a test on the site and 50% of the visitors should see an ad for a city page.

Comment: I just seen that and it looks good. Another feature that could be good is to cross reference your careers profile with the job listings to provide a targeted list of results as additional view!